# Why does it take longer for Linux to tell me that my user password is wrong, than it does for Windows?

Tags: windows-7, linux, passwords, linux-mint

I use both Linux Mint and Windows 7 depending on the task. I've noticed that when I try to login in with an incorrect password it takes longer to tell me so in Linux than it it does in Windows 7.

What is the reasoning for this? Is it to do with the levels of security?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Either system could tell you your password was wrong within milliseconds.  But to discourage attacks by repeated trial-and-error, it's simply good security practice to slow down the response in password systems. By how much is a design decision and will vary from one system to another.

Comment: [Obligatory TONT reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/23/9983312.aspx "Why does it take longer to reject an invalid password than to accept a valid one?"). :)

Comment: @Karan LOL.  Yes, yes.  I'm just picking off some low-hanging fruit to see if I can finish off the 5000 reputation thing.

Comment: So you're in a hurry to approve tag wiki edits? Nice, we need better tag wikis here. :)

Comment: Note, of course, that Windows will take much longer to tell you your password is wrong after a few attempts.